# Meteor App Environment Variables

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor and new to it. After some research, I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project). Exactly what I need as of the moment. I need to connect to an external mongodb somewhere in the server.

Now the question is where can I find the meteor config file (If ever if it's what I'm looking for) containing all environment variables (For example, MONGO_URL). If it's not any config file then how can I make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by setting the environment variable(s) directly on the command line or in a startup script. For a production use case, have a look at my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447818/keep-meteor-running-on-amazon-ec2) question.

When you are developing your app, on your localhost you can also have a script wrapper around your call to `meteor` like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
MONGO_URL="..." meteor
exit 0
```

or alternatively you can just add a line to your `~/.bashrc` to export the `MONGO_URL` variable to all console sessions.

There is no fully documented list of environment variables for meteor that I'm aware of, but an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600887/environment-variables-when-deploying-meteor) question lists a number of them. For nearly all circumstances, however, you need only a few and they appear in the meteor docs or somewhere in the [wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki).