# In Meteor.js, how would I have two development projects use the same Mongo instance?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to have two separate applications use the same Mongo DB instance, and since I am developing them at the same time I would like to be able to share the same development DB instance.

I realize that each instance of Meteor would have to run on it's own port.  Is there a way to force meteor or mrt to connect to a local socket like the system version of MongoDB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, you can just start meteor with the `MONGO_URL` parameter like:

```bash
$ MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp" meteor
```

or

```bash
$ MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp" meteor --port 4000
```

This assumes you have mongodb installed on your system. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518799/meteor-app-environment-variables/) for ways to make this process a little easier by using environment variables or a start script.

Answer (score 6):

David's answer is in the right direction, but threw me off a little. Instead, we're doing this to start the first app as normal:

```bash
$ meteor
```

Then to start the second app and connect to the database of the first, we're doing:

```bash
$ MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor" meteor --port 3002
```

The key here is that meteor starts its own mongo instance on port `3001`, and we can connect to that directly from a second meteor instance. David's answer uses your system's mongo for both apps.

Comment: I like the way you have it set up!  I probably won't end up using it though since I've found that I end up using the system mongo instance to do my velocity fixture loading as well using David's technique.

Comment: So glad I scrolled down, because while I understand David's answer, it also confused me for a moment, and I was actually wondering how to do exactly what you show here.  Thanks.