# Can I get multiple different Meteor apps running reactively off the same MongoDB instance?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to deploy the same app at a couple different locations, and perhaps also in different versions, and I'd like all my deployments to run off the same Mongo database.  Are there any pitfalls to taking this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have them use the same `MONGO_URL` and it will work fine. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529676/in-meteor-js-how-would-i-have-two-development-projects-use-the-same-mongo-insta). We do exactly that and  have not encountered any problems.

If you are running in multiple physical locations, keep in mind that mongodb traffic isn't sent over https. For this reason, the current best practice is to host your database and your app in the same in the same data center (e.g. use compose.io and host in EC2 east).