# How to start multiple application in same db?

Tags: meteor

I have to meteor application in local (admin and client). Applications run on different port `3000` and `3003`. I want to use both app should use the same DB. `export MONGO_URL=mobgodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor` will be okay. But I would like to know any argument to pass with meteor command to setup environment variable to use the same DB.

Comment: Refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135868/can-i-use-the-same-db-for-multiple-meteor-apps)

Comment: @Jesper. I just want this for development. for production, we can setup env variable `MONGO_URL`. I don't like to use `_driver` option in `Mongo.Collection`

Comment: @BlueBells are you just looking for a startup script so you have to do less typing?

Comment: @DavidWeldon exactly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a start script you could do the following:

In the root of your app, create a file called `start.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MONGO_URL=mobgodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor meteor --port 3000
```

Then run `chmod +x start.sh`

You can then start your app just by typing `./start.sh`