# MongoDB disabled by default

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I know there's a hack to achieve this running meteor as:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27766 meteor
```

But then i have to pass the parameter every time I run meteor. There's a cleaner way to do it?

I tried to set process.env.MONGO_URL in a startup function in /server but then the database is created anyway.

Comment: Does my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612768/how-to-start-multiple-application-in-same-db) help?

Comment: Indeed.  Different question but same solution.